# problema con indentado en python

Tags: python

Vengo de la vieja escuela en c(ansi c) y me acostumbre mucho a las llaves{},el programa corre bien pero no logro entender por que el metodo def worker() tiene que estar asi de indentado,me refiero a que si pongo print 'Starting %d processes...' % WORKER_NUMBER al mismo nivel que print "Hello, I am the process with PID %d" % PID me marca error y el "hello" lo imprime al final cuando pensaria que deberia ser lo primero en imprimir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import multiprocessing
import os


WORKER_NUMBER = 1

def worker():
    PID = os.getpid()
    print "Hello, I am the process with PID %d" % PID
print 'Starting %d processes...' % WORKER_NUMBER


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
    jobs = []
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa indentacion es correcta para python, pero seguramente no hace lo que esperas, ya que el segundo `print()` **está fuera de la función**, y por tanto no se ejecuta cuando llamas a la función, sino cuando python ha terminado de leer la definición de esa función y antes de pasar al `if _name_...`.

Es decir, python ejecuta en este orden:

1. Ejecuta los `import` iniciales (lo cual consiste en ejecutar el contenido de esos módulos)
2. Ejecuta la asignación `WORKER_NUMBER = 1`
3. Ejecuta el `def` (que no causa la ejecución de la función, sino su definición), Va guardando como código de esa función todo lo que esté a un mismo nivel de indentación.
4. Al detectar que la indentación se ha terminado, da por finalizado el código de la función, que sólo contendrá un `print`
5. Se encuentra otro `print`, que ejecuta ahí mismo
6. Se encuentra el `if`. Como la condición es cierta, pasa a interpetar lo que hay dentro.
7. Encuentra una llamada a `Process`, por lo que invoca esa función. Eso crea un nuevo proceso dedicado a ejecutar `worker` (pero no empieza aún su ejecución)
8. Añade el trabajo a la lista
9. Arranca el sub-proceso. En ese momento se ejecutará  `worker()` y saldrá el print contenido en esa función.
10. El proceso principal termina al llegar al final del programa. El subproceso termina también, prácticamente a la vez en este caso.

Supongo que lo que pretendías es que el segundo `print` formara parte del `worker()`. Para ello debe tener la misma indentación que el resto de líneas en esa función, es decir:

```
def worker():
    PID = os.getpid()
    print "Hello, I am the process with PID %d" % PID
    print 'Starting %d processes...' % WORKER_NUMBER
```

Si dices que has intentado esto y te ha dado error, es debido a que aunque "visualmente" tengan la misma indentación, "en realidad" no la tienen, seguramente porque las dos primeras usan cuatro espacios mientras que la última usa un TAB, o viceversa.

Esto de mezclar TAB y espacios es uno de los peores problemas a la hora de editar código python. Por suerte se resuelve tan pronto como empiezas a usar un buen editor que sea consciente de que está editando código python y así se comporte de forma consistente. Te recomiendo Visual Studio Code, o Vim. En su defecto busca qué opción tiene tu editor para "mostrar los caracteres invisibles" y así estar seguro de que siempre usas espacios y nunca tabuladores.